# Существует ли формат аудио файла с прописанным в нем тайм-кодом?

Tags: аудио, звукозапись

Например Wav файл с мета-данными, в которых прописан тайм-код. А точнее время, в котором этот файл должен находиться в проекте.

Comment: 1. Есть медиа-обвертки, которые позволяют вкладывать метаданные (flv, mp4, ... и т д.) 2. Некоторые другие форматы позволяют вкладывать метаданные (mp3 позволяет вкладывать картинки и некоторый текст, mid(rmi rich-midi) позволяет вкладывать метаданные (титры, wav-аудиоотрывки).

Comment: Какого вида метаданные имеется ввиду?  *время, в котором этот файл должен находиться в проекте* - не понятно что имеется ввиду.

Comment: Также, неясно что мешает положить таймкоды рядом или в метаданные. В общем вопрос неясен.

Comment: Эти данные нужны, чтобы импортируя такие файлы, они "сами" вставали в нужное место проекта по тайм линии.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду windows - то можно в ресурсы вшить несколько аудио, с определёнными именами. Меняя res-файл - звуки будут менятся...

Comment: Что представляет собой "тайм-линия"? Имеется ввиду звук - тишина - звук? Интервалы будут всегда одинаковые, или имеется ввиду слияние нескольких wav в один, и использование нужного фрагмента в нужное время?

Comment: Если это не касается программирования напрямую, то вам нужен или flv/mp4 или если требования высокие - то флеш (swf), и соответственно утилиты которые умеют правильно расставить звуки по тайм-линии (из платных - Adobe Premier). Так же возможно вам подойдет "презентация" (из ms-офис пакета)